# Make all div clickable and open link in a blank

Tags: jquery, html

I am tring to make a entire div clickable and to open the link in a blank page:

HTML code:

```
<div class="article-content">
    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
     <div><a href="http://www.google.ro" target="_blank">Click me</div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".article-content").click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

But every the link is opened in the same windows.

have any ideea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [use window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to open a new window

```
$(".article-content").click(function () {
    window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href"), '_blank');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `window.open` with target set to blank. link will be opened in popup window or new tab based on browser setting in users machine:

```
$(".article-content").click(function () {
 window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href"),'_blank');
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".article-content").click(function () {
        window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href"), '_blank');
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.